# Big Data with Minimal Disk Operation - MapReduce

Tags: mapreduce, analytics, hive, hdfs, bigdata

I need to process 10TB of text in thousands of files that are on a remote server. I wan to process them on my local machine with 3GB RAM, 50GB HDD. I need an abstract layer to download the files from the remote server on-demand, process them (mapreduce) then discard them, load some more files.

Regarding HDFS I need to load them to HDFS and then things should be straightforward but I need to do memory management myself. I want something that takes care of this. something like remote links in HDFS, or symbolic links in HDFS to a remote file that downloads them and loads them to memory process them then discard them move on to more files.

So for now I use Amplab spark to do the parallel processing for me, but on this level of processing it gives up.

I want a one liner in something like spark:

`myFilesRDD.map(...).reduce(...)`

RDD should take care of it

Answer (score 0):

Map/Reduce is for breaking up work over a cluster of machines.  It sounds like you have a single machine, your local one.  You might want to look at R, as it has built-in commands to load data across the net.  Out of the box, it won't give you the virtual memory-like facade you've described, but if you can tolerate writing an iterative loop and loading the data in chunks yourself, then R can not only give you the remote data loading you seek, R's rich collection of available libraries can facilitate any sort of processing you could desire.